# I want to get words in a JFrame2, go back to JFrame1 and then go to JFrame3 with these words. How can I do it?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

Well, I'm having this newbie problem right now.

I have **3 JFrames. JFrame1 opens JFrame2; JFrame2 gets the words and then re-opens JFrame1; JFrame1 opens JFrame3 with the words taken in JFrame2**.

The problem I'm having is about the creation of JFrame3. I mean, I know how to go from JFrame2 directly to JFrame3 (via constructor, passing by parameters the words I found). What I'm trying to do is **taking the words from JFrame2**, **putting it in JFrame3**, but **making this last one invisible** (this.setVisible(false)). And then, **when I go back to JFrame1**, and when I **click on a button**, it **redirects me to JFrame3 with the words from JFrame2**. Which I think it'd be something like [...].setVisible(true).

What I don't wanna do is to create a new JFrame3() when I click on the button on JFrame1. Because doing so, I'd lose all the things I got in JFrame2. So, basically, I just want to make the JFrame3 visible again. Without having to create a new one and losing all my stuff.

I hope someone can understand what I'm trying to say and can help me somehow.
Thanks in advance, guys. Sorry for the bad English.

By the way, I'm using **Netbeans-Java**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> JFrame1 opens JFrame2; JFrame2 gets the words and then re-opens
>   JFrame1; JFrame1 opens JFrame3 with the words taken in JFrame2.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MultiFrames implements ActionListener
{
    private JFrame frame1, frame2, frame3;
    private String message;
    private JTextField txtFiled;
    private JButton btn1, btn2;
    private JLabel lbl;
    private boolean flag = false;

    private static final String BUTTON1_COMMAND = "btn1";
    private static final String BUTTON2_COMMAND = "btn2";

    public MultiFrames()
    {
        frame1 = new JFrame("JFrame #1");
        frame2 = new JFrame("JFrame #2");
        frame3 = new JFrame("JFrame #3");

        frame1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame3.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame1.setSize(200, 100);
        frame1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame2.setSize(200, 100);
        frame2.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame3.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame3.setSize(200, 100);
        frame3.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        txtFiled = new JTextField(10);
        frame2.add(txtFiled);

        lbl = new JLabel();
        frame3.add(lbl);

        btn1 = new JButton("Open JFrame #2");
        btn2 = new JButton("Re-Open JFrame #1");

        btn1.addActionListener(this);
        btn1.setActionCommand(BUTTON1_COMMAND);
        btn2.addActionListener(this);
        btn2.setActionCommand(BUTTON2_COMMAND);

        frame1.add(btn1);
        frame2.add(btn2);

        frame1.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String s = e.getActionCommand();

        if(s.equals(BUTTON1_COMMAND))
        {
            if(!flag)
            {
                frame1.setVisible(false);
                frame2.setVisible(true);
                flag = true;
            }
            else
            {
                frame1.setVisible(false);
                frame3.setVisible(true);
                lbl.setText("The word is: " + message);
            }
        }
        else if(s.equals(BUTTON2_COMMAND))
        {
            frame2.setVisible(false);
            frame1.setVisible(true);
            message = txtFiled.getText();
            btn1.setText("Open JFrame #3");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new MultiFrames();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Eng. I'll take a close look at it and see what I can do from there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you have a reason to have three separate JFrames, but if not, try looking into the CardLayout LayoutManager. Instead of making separate JFrames you would make separate JPanels and just add them to this CardLayout. [CardLayout in the API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html)

Comment: This would make it easy to edit components in each of the separate JPanels, as well as switch which one is visible. There is also a good tutorial by Oracle if you search Google for "java 6 CardLayout"

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers, guys. But I do need to work with these three JFrames.

Answer (score 1):

Recommendation: don't use NetBeans to generate your Swing code as it actually hinders your learning of Swing and gets you into bad habits like popping JFrames willy-nilly. Learn from the tutorials how to code Swing by hand. Then get your words perhaps in a dialog window such as provided by a JOptionPane or JDialog or perhaps by swapping JPanels with a CardLayout.

If you use modal dialogs, you'll know when one dialog has finished as code will resume right after the dialog was set visible. Then you can query the dialog class for the data obtained. Otherwise if you persist in using JFrames, you'll need to add WindowListeners to the frames to know when they've been made invisible which is a little more difficult to do.

For e.g.,

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FrameFoolery {
   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame Foolery");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new MainPanel(frame));
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class MainPanel extends JPanel {
   private String words = "";
   private JDialog dialog1;
   private JDialog dialog2;
   private Panel1 panel1;
   private Panel1 panel2;

   public MainPanel(final JFrame frame) {
      add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Show Dialog 1") {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            if (panel1 == null) {
               panel1 = new Panel1();
               dialog1 = new JDialog(frame, "Dialog 1", true);
               dialog1.getContentPane().add(panel1);
               dialog1.pack();
               Point pt = frame.getLocation();
               dialog1.setLocation(pt.x - 100, pt.y - 100);
            }
            dialog1.setVisible(true);
            words = panel1.getWords();
         }
      }));
      add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Show Dialog 2") {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            if (panel2 == null) {
               panel2 = new Panel1();
               dialog2 = new JDialog(frame, "Dialog 2", true);
               dialog2.getContentPane().add(panel2);
               dialog2.pack();
               dialog2.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
               Point pt = frame.getLocation();
               dialog2.setLocation(pt.x + 100, pt.y + 100);
            }
            panel2.setWords(words);
            dialog2.setVisible(true);
         }
      }));
   }
}

class Panel1 extends JPanel {
   private JTextField wordsField = new JTextField(20);

   Panel1() {
      add(new JLabel("Words:"));
      add(wordsField);
      add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("OK") {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(Panel1.this);
            win.setVisible(false);
         }
      }));
   }

   public String getWords() {
      return wordsField.getText();
   }

   public void setWords(String words) {
      wordsField.setText(words);
   }


}
```

Comment: Oh, I see. That's a pretty good point you make. But.. there's no way that I can just.. make the JFrame3 visible again? Since I just put it in setVisible(false) in jFrame2?

Comment: Because everything is already done in JFrame3. And to change it all, I think I'd have to start all over again, which'd give a hell lot of work.

Comment: You should gear your Swing GUI creation to creating JPanels not JFrames, or JDialogs. That way you can put your panels in anything you wish. But to flip JFrames is not the right thing to do. I suggest that you just don't do this.

Comment: @enso don't do it that, don't use more that one JFrame in one JVM instance, it wrong to use same Component hierarchy, there are lots common issue with that, as suggested HFOE change another to the JDialog, if not then implemnts CardLayout

Comment: Thanks for all the tips, guys. I'll see what I can do from here.

Comment: @enso: please see example above.

Comment: Yeah, I'm taking a look at those. Thank you for all the help.